# What is the sense of using "have had" in this context?

Tags: grammar

Context:

> When I have had the food, then only I will tell you the story.

What is the sense of using "have had" here?

I am thinking that the sentence should be :: When I will have the food, then only I will tell you the story.

Comment: "Have" takes a multitude of meanings in English. Here it means "eat". The modal _will_ has no meaning or use here. _"When I have had the food"_ means only _"When I have **eaten** the food"._

Answer (score 1):

Here to "have" the food means to have it to eat. To "have had" the food means to have finished eating it. He refuses to tell the story until they bring him food and allow him to eat it.

The sentence you propose is unusually worded, but grammatically correct. However, it does not mean the same thing as the original sentence. You sentence means that he is willing to start speaking as soon as the food is placed on the table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rigid rule that the future tense must be used for all future actions in English. Quite often another tense is used.

In sentences of the form, "When I _____, then I will _____," referring to two actions that will occur in the future, the first blank is typically filled by a verb in the present tense.
In some cases it is possible to use present perfect, as in the example in the question, or present progressive.

Here is are similar sentences in which the verb *eat* appears in each
of these three tenses:

> When I am eating the food, I will tell the story.

In this case the telling of the story will not commence until the speaker has started eating, but it (probably) will occur while the speaker is still eating. (Between mouthfuls, one hopes!)

> When I have eaten the food, then I will tell the story.

In this case the telling of the story will commence after the speaker has finished eating.

> When I eat the food, then I will tell the story.

In this case the present tense is a bit awkward. It is unclear whether the telling of the story is likely to occur while the speaker is still eating or only after the speaker has finished eating. Perhaps the speaker expects to be eating the food on several future occasions and intends to tell the story on each of those occasions.

As noted in another answer, in the example in the question "had" is used in the sense of "eaten."

The future tense will usually seem out of place in such a context to a native speaker of American English (and I think British English as well)
and is best avoided.
See [“When X is” or “When X will be”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22752/when-x-is-or-when-x-will-be)

Answer (score 0):

> When I have had the food, then only I will tell you the story.

"[to have](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have)" here means to eat or drink something *(see '**have verb (EAT/DRINK)**')*. It is in the past tense "**have had**" meaning "**have something eaten**". The first part means, "*When I have finished eating the food*".

The second part means that "*only after that I will tell you the story*".

The sentence can be phrased differently to make it easier to understand:

- Only when I have finished eating *(have had the food)* I will tell you the story.

<sub>P.s. *as non-native speaker I find the part "**then only I will**" quite unidiomatic.*</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Unless you are referencing a specific food (like *the hot dog in front of you*) *the* should be omitted because it is not definite. *Only* must be put before *then* because then *only* describes *then* not *I*.  Otherwise, the sentence says that when you have food, nobody else will tell the story, only you.  When I will have can be shortened to When I have, since when indicates that it will be in the future.  When I will have sounds strange to me, an American.

Comment: The determiner is idiomatic in such things as _"When I have eaten the food"_.